# How can I get the layout xml from webDriver.io for android native app?

Tags: android, selenium, webdriver-io, appium-android

I'm using WebDriver.io to create tests.
In the [Docs](http://webdriver.io/api/property/getSource.html) getSource doesn't support native apps.

> Get source code of the page. This command won’t work in mobile
>   environments for native apps. If you are running hybrid tests make
>   sure that you are in the webview before calling this command.

For now, I use "client.source()" [link](http://webdriver.io/api/protocol/source.html) which return the XML but can take up to 20 sec.

How can I get the layout XML from webDriver.io?

Comment: This isn't a common question in the WDIO scene, but I think you might have more success asking directly on their **[Official WebdriverIO Gitter](https://gitter.im/webdriverio/webdriverio)** channel. I've found a lot of answers to obscure questions there. Also the framework's creator is very active there. Ask him directly via *@christian-bromann*.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it the right way. Alternatively you can try the **[WD.js](https://github.com/admc/wd)** client and check if performance will be better with than the other one, or simply open an issue report on the **[WebdriverIO Github](https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/issues)** page.

The reason of why it may take so long:

- UI of the app is constantly updating => Appium is hanging for a bit to retrieve it;
- Lots of elements on your app page => leads to a big `.xml` file.